# Decrease in density due to relative velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

A moving frame sees density of a spherical body decreased by 20% of its density in rest frame . What is the velocity of the moving frame ?

I thought moving frame observes change in length of object in only one dimension (as length parallel to relative motion is only affected) and volume becomes V/gamma and found the results accordingly . I am not sure my approach is right or not .If not please help me with correct solution.

Comment: the length contracts, so the volume is less and the density increases, it cannot decrease

Comment: I am absolutely sorry for the mistake; it has to be increased

Comment: Hi Deepak and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).